# shell scripting grep command

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I want to find whether a string contains a forward slash using "grep" command. It is easy at the beginning, and I wrote the following script.

```
foo=someone/books
if [ `echo "$foo" | grep '/'` ]
then
    echo "has forward slash"
fi
```

however, the problem is in the corner, if I set the variable "foo"  to the following string,

```
foo="someone/books in stack"
```

The above script will be failed since there is "space" in variable foo, when the command expands, the condition in if statement is as below.

```
grep '/' someone/books in stack
```

Because of "space", the above "grep" command has too many arguments that is illegal. FYI, I try to solved this problem using case statement:

```
case $foo in
    */*)
        echo "has forward slash"
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
```

However, I do not want to use case statement since it's verbose. So how could I solved this problem using grep command or others?

Comment: actually the problem does not exist the way you describe it - if you pipe a text with spaces into grep, it will work just fine, because it'll never expand it onto greps command line like you described. Verify again that `echo "stuff with/ spaces" | grep '/'` actually works fine

Comment: @Yefim Dinitz in fact, I try it. It does not work fine

Comment: then you must be using the strangest `grep` I've ever seen...

Comment: @Yefim Dinitz In fact, if I write this command into script, it will not worked find. however if I write this command in the terminal, it will work find, So why?

Comment: dogbane spotted your error :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the if-statement correctly. The command in the if-condition needs to be quoted so that it becomes a single string when expanded. Like this:

```
if [ "`echo "$foo" | grep '/'`" ]
then
    echo "has forward slash"
fi
```

Or even better is if you check the return code of grep in your if-condition:

```
if $(echo "$foo" | grep -q '/')
then
    echo "has forward slash"
fi
```

You can also do away with the `grep` and use this instead:

```
foo="someone/books in stack"
if [[ "$foo" == */* ]]
then
  echo "has forward slash"
fi
```

Comment: I know. But what about /bin/sh rather than /bin/bash

Answer (score 0):

```
foo="someone/books with spaces"
bar=`echo $foo | grep '/'`
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "$foo has forward slash"
fi
```

This works for me.

If you don't want to resort to using exit status this way, I suggest you take a look at dogbane's reply for a more correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with being verbose -- it often aids maintainability. However, you can terse it up: You don't need every newline, nor do you need the default branch if you do nothing in it.

```
case "$foo" in
    */*) echo "has forward slash" ;;
esac
```

If you insist on using grep, use the return status from it and not the output:

```
if echo "$foo" | grep -q /; then
    echo "has forward slash"
fi
```